# How to combine two SQL SELECT statements in one?

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two SELECT statements:

```
SELECT Termin FROM crSpielTermine WHERE Status = 1
```

and this

```
SELECT TerminID FROM crSpielTermine WHERE Termin > ".$AlterTermin." ORDER BY Termin LIMIT 1
```

Right now, the first select supplies me `$AlterTermin` which I'm using in the
second statement.

Can I combine these two statements and if yes, how I'm going to do this?

Comment: yes you can do using sub query

Comment: The first query always returns just one record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing that your first select returns only a single item, you'd have something like that:

```
SELECT TerminID
FROM crSpielTermine
WHERE Termin > (SELECT Termin FROM crSpielTermine WHERE Status = 1)
ORDER BY Termin
LIMIT 1
```

Or this just to make sure it returns only one item

```
SELECT TerminID
FROM crSpielTermine
WHERE Termin > (SELECT Termin FROM crSpielTermine WHERE Status = 1 LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY Termin
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The first statement works perfect! The second one returns all ids :/

Comment: It's like I said. Do your first query always returns only one result? If so, the my first option will work.

Comment: @Phiter Fernandes what should be the solution if the first select returns multiple values? thanks.

Comment: @FaiyazAlam that would be the second one which limits the results to one value.

Comment: Oh sry, i understand now. Yes my first query returns only one result. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help ;D

Comment: @egolive I was missing the LIMIT in the outer query in both of them, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You may use sub-query as follows which will give same result :

```
SELECT TerminID FROM crSpielTermine 
WHERE Termin > (SELECT Termin FROM  crSpielTermine WHERE Status = 1) 
ORDER BY Termin LIMIT 1
```